# Full-wave rectifier with filter

Tags: capacitor, rectifier

Assume we have a full-wave rectifier bridge circuit connected to a load made of a resistor with resistance R and a capacitor with capacitance C in parallel to each other.

In the first quarter-period, the capacitor is obviously charging with the diode from the rectifier on (We assume it is ideal and that the connecting wires are ideal as well.). However, from the quarter period to the half of the period, I have no idea how to get an analytical formula and derive whether the capacitor charges or discharges.

How do we get an exact equation governing the capacitor and when exactly does it start discharging? Does it do so exactly at the quarter period or does it start discharging after a certain angle?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Are you after an equation of the capacitor voltage or current?

Comment: Anything that would show me when the capacitor starts discharging and/or when the diode blocks.

Comment: There are two cases, the diode conducts or it doesn't. This is determined by the voltage across the diode. Start with the case that it doesn't conduct. What will be the voltage across the RC load? That's described by the RC discharge formula. What does the input voltage do? That's described by a sinewave. What happens if the sinewave drops faster than the voltage across the RC load? And what if it doesn't? In which case would the diode conduct and what would that mean for the voltage across the load? How does the RC product relate to this?

Comment: For the capacitor to discharge so we can apply the RC discharge formula, doesnt the diode have to be in reverse bias?

Comment: If the diode wasn't in reverse bias but **conducting** then current would be flowing into the RC load. Do you think you can still apply the RC discharge formula? What situation does that formula describe?

Comment: I know we couldnt apply it then, but how would we know beforehand that it would be in reverse bias so we could apply it?

Comment: No, it isn't a duplicate. Check the comments, a totally different matter